# Call a oracle function that returns a cursor

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

I have an Oracle Function that takes an input parameter and returns a cursor.
I am using C# to invoke the Oracle Function, however, I am not able to retrieve the Cursor.

My Oracle Function Call is as follows:-

```
select TBL_POWER_VIEW.GET_POWER_ID('V') FROM DUAL;
```

My C# Code is:

```
conn = new OracleConnection(OracleServer);
conn.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "TBL_POWER_VIEW.GET_POWER_ID";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = conn;


OracleParameter powerId = new OracleParameter("i_power_flg", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
powerId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
powerId.Value = 'L';
cmd.Parameters.Add(powerId);

OracleParameter oraP = new OracleParameter();
oraP.ParameterName = "TEST_CURSOR";
oraP.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
oraP.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(oraP);

OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand=cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Error Stack is as follows:-

> A first chance exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_CURSOR'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=googlr&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#safe=off&q=ado.net+oracle+cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following

```
// Use Return instead of Output in Function 
oraP.Direction = ParameterDirection.Return;
```

!!! Return parameter must be listed first unless you do

```
cmd.BindByName = true;
```

This should take care of it